# HTML Parsing in Razor Helpers

Tags: c#, html, parsing, razor

I've got the following code,

```
@helper Category(IGroup group)
{
  if (!group.Exist)
  {
    return;
  }
  var colors = AppContext.Settings.Colors.Charts.Net;
  var css = group.Name.Replace(" ", String.Empty).ToLower();
  var id = css.ToUpper() + "_";

  <tr>
        <td class="summarygridbackground" style="font-weight:bold;">@group.Name</td>
    </tr>
  foreach(var category in group.Categories)
  {
        <tr id="@id@category.Id" class="summarygridbackground">
        <td class="category">
            <div style="float:left">@category.Name</div>
            <div class="hovericon">@FormatAs.Currency(category.TotalValue)</div>
    </td>
      </tr>
  }
    <tr class="summarygridbackground">
      @switch(css)
        {
          case "inv":
            <text>
              <td class ="@css" style="color: @colors.Inv.html">
            </text>
            break;
          case "other":
            <text>
              <td class ="@css" style="color: @colors.Other.html">
            </text>
            break;
          case "lib":
            <text>
              <td class ="@css" style="color: @colors.Lib.html">
            </text>
            break;
          case "net":
            <text>
              <td class ="@css" style="color: @colors.Net.html">
            </text>
            break;
          default:
            <text>
              <td class="@css">
            </text>
            break;
        }

          <div style="float:left; padding-left:12px;"> Total @group.Name</div>
            <div style="float:right; padding-right:10px;">@FormatAs.Currency(group.TotalValue)</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

As it stands, the code fails on the last line of the helper when I load the view, with the following message:

> Parser Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this >request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source >file appropriately.
>
> "Parser Error Message: Encountered end tag "tr" with no matching start
>   tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 65:          @FormatAs.Currency(group.TotalValue) Line
>   66:        Line 67:   Line 68: }"

When I remove that last `</tr>` on the last line, it fails with this message:

> Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The "tr" element was not closed.  All elements
>   must be either self-closing or have a matching end tag.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 32:     Line 33:   } Line 34:    Line 35:       @switch(css)

I can't figure it out, that's the entire helper method, it looks balanced to me, and all calls to this helper both worked fine previously, and are not nested in `<tr>`s, only `<div>`s

Could someone please help me?

Edit: I managed to make it work by removing the `switch` from that segment, and instead using it at the beginning of the `foreach` to set a `var color`, and using that instead. This seems like it's a better solution anyway, but I'd still like to understand *why* it is that the first attempt didn't work.

Comment: -1. Next time please make an effort to have sample of about 5-7 lines. There is also good chance if you've tried it for this question you'd find answer yourself.

Comment: Sorry, the first couple questions I asked I ended up being asked to provide additional context in short order, so I thought I'd give a reasonably full context initially this time.

Answer (score 1):

Your TD is not closed properly.  Remove the `</text>` from the case statement and move it after the `</td>`:

```
<tr class="summarygridbackground">
  @switch(css)
    {
      case "inv":
        <text>
          <td class ="@css" style="color: @colors.Inv.html">
        </text>
        break;
      case "other":
        <text>
          <td class ="@css" style="color: @colors.Other.html">
        break;
      case "lib":
        <text>
          <td class ="@css" style="color: @colors.Lib.html">

        break;
      case "net":
        <text>
          <td class ="@css" style="color: @colors.Net.html">

        break;
      default:
        <text>
          <td class="@css">

        break;
    }

      <div style="float:left; padding-left:12px;"> Total @group.Name</div>
        <div style="float:right; padding-right:10px;">@FormatAs.Currency(group.TotalValue)</div>
    </td>
        </text>
</tr>
```

Comment: Without the </text>, the breaks and later cases no longer appear as keywords, and I get the Control cannot fall through message. My impression was that <text> in this case wasn't an html tag, but a Razor marker specifying that what was inside was html. Is that incorrect?